# Maven Dependency Tree by Package

Tags: maven

I merged a couple Maven projects together and now assume that the dependencies are overlapping, e.g. there might be different implementations used for the same packages or even multiple dependencies exporting the same package.

I want to find a way to reduce the overlap.

The `maven-dependency-plugin` is probably a good starting point, and `dependency:tree` prints the dependency tree - only it prints the JAR artefacts, and there is no easy way for me to know which packages they export.

`dependency:unpack` let's me see the packages of all dependencies, but since there are all in the same folder I cannot see if these packages are used by multiple dependencies.

I could probably use `copy-dependencies` and just unzip all JARs manuall into the same folder and see if there are error messages, but that seems a bit unrefined.

Is there an easier way to check the packages of the dependency tree in Maven?

Comment: Simple answer: No. If you have several implementations which means having the same package name and the same Classname? shouldn't that fail via unit tests etc. ? Or shouldn't it produce errors?

Comment: @khmarbaise I don't think it should. If one module builds its test against implementation A and another one against implementation B that's perfectly valid (but might lead to errors later on). If two dependencies contain the same package, the classloader loads the first one (IMHO), and the second one is ignored, so right now there is a reproducible behavior that might change during little changes like ordering the dependencies differently or a new Maven version.

Comment: simply remove the dependencies step by step and see until your build fails ...then you know what you build really needs...

Comment: @khmarbaise I already did that. There's even a nifty plug-in for that, `maven-dependency-plugin` with `dependency:analyze` tells you which dependencies are unecessary.